# How to fork a GitHub repository if I'm the owner

Tags: git, github, git-pull, git-fork

Although this is not a code question but code-related question. So I think programmers are the righ people to help me.

I have a private repository for collaborative project. I created the repository so I'm the repo. owner. I  need to fork and make pull requests to the project collaborator. I tried to add myself as a collaborator but GiHub says I can not be added as a collaborator as I'm the project owner. Also the fork icon is disabled and I can not make a fork.

I own the repo. but it is a shared project where I need to fork and do my changes then make a pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a branch, push it and then create a PR from it. https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/